# MATLAB: Alternative to using 'eval' in order to evaluate string

Tags: string, matlab, char, eval

I have a bunch of char arrays within a cell array that actually represents the declaration of MATLAB structs. Something like this:

```
tmp{1} = 'testData.input = [1;2;3;4;5]'
tmp{2} = 'testData.output = [2;4;6;8;10]'
```

I need to execute these "commands" and eventually create the respective struct. I am using the `eval` function within a for-loop and it works.

```
numEntries = numel(tmp);
for i = 1 : numEntries
    eval(tmp{i});
end
```

However, this is painfully slow. I should mention that the real char arrays are very large, effectively containing more than 3,000 numbers. Also, the `tmp` cell array itself contains some 25,000 cells.
Is there a way to improve performance given that I can't change the input data, i.e. `tmp` is simply given from an external source?

Comment: Do you care about the names of the structs defined in `tmp`? If not then i would create a cell array of `numel(tmp)`, read each line, split it into the fieldname and data, then use [setField](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html) to assign the data to that field. 
Otherwise all i can think of is using the parallel toolbox if you have it and just doing a parfor loop.

Comment: I overlooked the fact that the structures are defined over multiple elements of tmp. You could just check if the structure name has changed in comparison to the previous one and moving to the next element in the cell array accordingly

Comment: You need to evaluate all the strings. After evaluations save the created variables in a .mat file for future use.

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

Comment: @AlexanderVandenberghe I actually do care about the struct names. As far as I understand it, using `eval` in conjunction with parfor may lead to errors.

Comment: @rahnema1 That's exactly what I am doing right now. However, I regularly have to evaluate new `tmp` cell arrays.

Comment: I have no idea . Providing more details about the structure of data or explaining that why you regularly have to evaluate new tmp cell arrays may be helpful.

Comment: You may want to try different methods for [converting from string to numeric](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/converting-from-string-to-numeric.html).

Answer (score 4):

I cannot test if it is significantly faster with only the 2 lines you gave as an example but I would expect this method to be faster when the number of elements of `tmp` grows.

The idea is to write all the assignment instructions contained into `tmp` into a text file (an `.m` file actually), then simply execute the `.m` file. For large number of lines I would expect that to be way faster than having to invoque `eval` repeatedly in a loop.

So here goes, this works fine with your example `tmp`, you end up with the structure `testData` in your workspace.

```
%% Create an '.m' file containing all the assignment instructions from the cell array
tmpFile  = 'tmpFile2execute.m' ;
fidw = fopen( tmpFile , 'w' ) ;
fprintf(fidw,'%% Auto generated file\n'); % or any other header line you want, or none...
for i = 1 : numel(tmp) ;
    fprintf(fidw,'%s ;\n',tmp{i});
end
fclose(fidw) ;
% (optional) only to keep workspace tidy
clear i fidw tmpFile tmp 

%% Execute the file
tmpFile2execute ;
```

---

Expanding on the idea you could make it a `function` instead of a `script`, where you could add some post processing and return the result in a variable instead of directly in the workspace but you have to see if the base idea brings any speed improvment first.

Comment: This may be an interesting alternative. However, I can't measure any significant advantage in terms of performance. Also, I am facing the issue that the created .m file is quie large (~500MB). I can't execute it due to RAM issues (16GB). (My tmp variable contains ~25,000 elements. Each element defines a col vector with ~3,000 rows, each containing a float with 7 decimals). Therefore, I have to split the file and use a loop.

Comment: ouch ... indeed a 500MB text file is certainly a big chunck you would want to partition for easier handling. But It makes me wonder who designed the output of these tests. This `tmp` variables are just about the _least efficient_ way of storing large numerical results. Sure you could improve your way of parsing that `tnp` structure, but the biggest efficiency gain by far would be to modify the way it is created ... do you have any control over that ?

Comment: Sorry I noticed in your original post that you cannot change the format of `tmp`. When you load `tmp` into matlab, what kind of size does it take ? (use `whos tmp` in the console to get the full size). And once it is all parsed, what typical size is `testData`? I can modify my solution to generate several reasonnably sized `.m` files instead of a huge one if it would help you.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, I already looped through some smaller .m files. I actually split them into 26 chunks. This basically worked. But the performance improved not as much as I hoped. Let's say, something in the range of 20%-30%. While the `eval` solution takes about 45 minutes, the `.m-file` solution takes some 35 minutes. If I could bring it down to less than 5 minutes, this would help a lot.

Comment: As I said, let us know the full size in memory of `tmp` and `testData`. I doubt there will be a way to reduce the time to 5 min until the input format is changed. At the moment, regardless of the solution, we are still talking of parsing a very large number of strings. This is slow regardless of the method used. I would recommend you to parse these files as soon as they arrive then save the result in a `.mat` file (or any binary format convenient for you), so the 30-45min effort is only spent once.

Comment: Now, let's turn our attention to `tmp`. It's actually an output from a huge Excel sheet. Depending on a number of user defined settings, many columns will be recalculated. Every set of settings represents the basis for a unit test in MATLAB. That is, I need a lot of columns/matrices that belong to a given state of settings. That's why I need a `struct` in MATLAB. Every field of this `struct` represents one variation within the unit test. In Excel, VBA code loops through all the possible combinations of settings and save the results as huge strings (which are then executable in MATLAB).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185253/discussion-between-hoki-and-andi).

Answer (score 0):

`cellfun(@eval,tmp);` will somewhat improve the performance over a loop. Otherwise, you may have to write your own parser (which may be faster if a limited type of input is expected, e.g. only assignment like *structure*.*some_field*.*some_other_subfield* = [*some_array*]; ).

Please note that `eval` is a risky function to use (if Mr. Mischief writes in the input data something like `!rm -Rf /` , `!del *.*` or `rmdir(matlabroot,'s')` you may end-up with a big mess evaluating those strings)

Comment: The structure is actually quite complex (up to seven sub-fields).

Comment: I know that `eval` may be somewhat risky. That's also a reason why I am looking for an alternative.