# MATLAB: Importing Excel matrices into structure

Tags: excel, matlab, struct, import

I am looking for a way to import Excel matrices into a MATLAB struct. Let's consider the following toy example.

In Excel the ranges `"A1:C1000"` and `"D1:F1000"` contains the first two matrices. I would like to import them into MATLAB and automatically save/convert them to a struct called `testData.input.firstInput` and `testData.input.secondInput`. Let's further assume that the ranges `"G1:K1000"` and `"L1:P1000"` hold some other data which I would like to save/convert into `testData.output.firstOutput` and `testData.output.secondOutput`.

The resulting struct looks like this:

```
testData
testData.input
testData.input.firstInput      % holds a 1000x3 matrix
testData.input.secondInput     % holds a 1000x3 matrix
testData.output.firstOutput    % holds a 1000x3 matrix
testData.output.secondOutput   % holds a 1000x3 matrix
```

I am wondering what's the best way to achieve this. Also, I would like to name the matrices in Excel according to the complete structure path. Where should I save this information in the Excel sheet? I need a solutaion where MATLAB doesn't know the structure names in advance, i.e. I need to import that information as well.

The next step would contain 3D matrices. Imagine in Excel the ranges `"A1:C1000"` and `"D1:F1000"` represent two pages of a 3D matrix. That is, in MATLAB it would be a `1000x3x2` matrix. I need to save/convert it into one struct field as well (e.g. `testData.output.first3Dmat`)

Comment: In MATLAB, I would create a cell array containing all the reference information. i.e. in column 1 you have if it's an input or output, column 2 has the name of the input/output, column 3 has the Excel sheet, column 4 has the Excel range etc. Meta data for one matrix per row in this cell array. Then you can simply loop through the array, and assign like `testData.(c{j,1}).(c{j,2}) = xlsread( filename, c{j,3}, c{j,4} );`, where `c` is the cell array. You can store other meta data in this one place. Or kill Excel, store data in .mat files, and just stick to MATLAB!

Comment: @Wolfie, He is actually saving test results in excel, and wants to import it in MATLAB. MATLAB does not know beforehand the structure of the saved excel sheet. Still your idea still holds, with an additional requirement for Andi: When you generate your excel sheet tables, add one sheet containing the structure names and informations as Wolfie described above (the sheet will act as the equivalent of a _header_ for tabular data). In Matlab read that sheet first and parse it, so you know the structure details, then import each field as Wolfie descibed above.

Comment: @Hoki Or write all the data to Excel from row 2, and in row 1 of each sheet store all the meta data for that sheet. Then just loop through the sheets in MATLAB, retrieve this meta data, then retrieve everything else. Reading from and writing to Excel is generally best avoided with MATLAB though, if Andi is using Excel as an intermediate storage location then there are definitely better alternatives (like just saving the structure with all the data in a mat file!!)

Comment: @Wolfie, Yes there are better way to save data, but his experimental data are computed in VBA so saving in '.xlsb' file makes sense. This is already an improvment compared to his old ways (saved in text values in excel sheets), as you can see from his former question: [MATLAB: Alternative to using 'eval' in order to evaluate string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762613/matlab-alternative-to-using-eval-in-order-to-evaluate-string), and the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185253/discussion-between-hoki-and-andi) that followed.

Comment: @Wolfie This might be an interesting idea. I will test it soon and let you know.

Comment: I think this is totally possible.  Could you please post a sample data file and also show what code you've tried to get this to work?

Comment: One more complication could be the fact that the structure may have a variable number of fields. In addition to my `testData` struct in the question, another part could look like this: `testData.output.thirdOutput.settingsA` and `testData.output.thirdOutput.settingsB`.

Comment: Or just use separate sheets....